# Необходимо написать рекурсивную процедуру, которая печатает элементы из всех листьев дерева

Tags: рекурсия, pascalabc.net

Столкнулся с задачкой:
Написать рекурсивную процедуру, которая печатает элементы из всех листьев дерева. Код, со всеми переменными, т.е. - полностью рабочую программу (код дерева).

Есть наброски:

```
type
  tTree = ^rTree;
  rTree = record
    N : Integer;
    L, R : tTree;
  end;

procedure TreePrint(Tree : tTree);
begin
  if Tree^.L <> nil then TreePrint(Tree^.L);
  Write(' ', Tree^.N);
  if Tree^.R <> nil then TreePrint(Tree^.R);
end;
```

Полистал похожую тему, но полноценного ответа не нашёл.
Нужно объединить в полностью рабочую программу.

Заранее спасибо за помощь:)

Comment: а то что есть чем не нравится? Вроде бы работать должно.

Comment: Необходимо написать код дерева (ввести элементы листьев дерева, и т.д., чтобы сама программа работала

Comment: Проще говоря - вызвать процедуру